# startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, core-motion, swift2

I am trying to translate the following code to Swift 2.

```
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in              
    self!.outputAccData(data.acceleration)
}
```

But this gives me the following error.

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those problems that can be solved by retyping the code from scratch. It appears that the second parameter to `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue()` is  now an object of type `(CMAccelerometerData?, NSError?) -> Void` instead of `(CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) -> Void`. You just need to rewrite your call to reflect this.

```
manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { [weak self] (data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) in
    self!.outputAccData(data.acceleration)
}
```